# Why isn't this Sum() in my index working?

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have the following test:

```
public class ListingEventTest
{
    public ListingEventTest()
    {
        Artists = new List<ArtistTest>();
    }
    public List<ArtistTest> Artists { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Popularity { get; set; }
}

public class ArtistTest
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Stat Stats { get; set; }
}

public class Stat
{
    public double Popularity { get; set; }
}


public class ArtistsWithStats_ByName : AbstractIndexCreationTask<ListingEventTest>
{
    public ArtistsWithStats_ByName()
    {
        Map = listingEvents => from listingEvent in listingEvents
                               let artists = LoadDocument<ArtistTest>(listingEvent.Artists.Select(x => x.Id))
                               select new
                               {
                                   Popularity = artists.Average(x => x.Stats.Popularity),
                                   listingEvent.Name
                               };
    }
}



[TestFixture]
public class IndexCanDoSums
{
    [Test]
    public async void WhenListingEventArtistsHaveStatsIndexReturnsPopularity()
    {
        var store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
        {
            UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true,
            Configuration =
            {
                RunInUnreliableYetFastModeThatIsNotSuitableForProduction = true,
                RunInMemory = true,

            }
        }.Initialize();

        IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(ArtistsWithStats_ByName).Assembly, store);

        using (var session = store.OpenAsyncSession())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var le = new ListingEventTest
                {
                    Name = "test-" + i
                };

                await session.StoreAsync(le);

                for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                {
                    var artist = new ArtistTest
                    {
                        Stats = new Stat
                        {
                            Popularity = 0.89d
                        }
                    };

                    await session.StoreAsync(artist);

                    le.Artists.Add(artist);
                }

                await session.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }

        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        using (var session = store.OpenAsyncSession())
        {
             var query = session
            .Advanced.AsyncLuceneQuery<ListingEventTest>("ArtistsWithStats/ByName");

            var result = await query.ToListAsync();

            result.First().Popularity.Should().NotBe(0);
        }
    }
}
```

When I query this index `Popularity` is always 0.

Any ideas?

Comment: Give a small, complete example that demonstrates the problem that we can actually try.

Comment: But this should work right?

Comment: Well no, the code as you've typed it in won't even compile because there's no comma after `.Name`.  Saying what it *should* or *shouldn't* do is a moral question; you're claiming that it *does* do a particular thing; demonstrating that the claim is correct is the first step in understanding it.  It could be that you've made more typos, and those explain the unexpected result. It could be that the artist in question has stats that sum to zero.

Comment: I'll set up a failing test

Comment: @EricLippert Updated the q with a failing test

Comment: Excuse the use of Average, I was just trying something out. Both Sum and Average will fail

Comment: I would use transformers but they aren't available in the lucene api :/

Comment: Why the downvote?! some people really are just w*^^kers!

Answer (score 1):

Some funny things going on here.

First, you are storing ArtistTest under the ListingEventTest document, not as separate documents, so in your index there is no need to call LoadDocument, you could just do:

```
from listingEvent in listingEvents
from artist in listingEvent.Artists
select ...
```

Second, a Map-only index is a lot like a SQL index where you're just calling out the columns you want to be able to query on. Here, you're doing a calculation on a set of buried properties and you have a top-level property where you want to store that information, but how that ends up working is that your calculated property value goes into the Lucene index (so you could query by Popularity if you want) but the data that is returned is straight from the unaltered document. The map defines what goes into Lucene, which points to the document id, and then the document store returns the documents as the results.

This could be modified somewhat by calling `Store(x => x.Popularity)` in the index's constructor, which would store the value to be recalled later, but honestly offhand I'm not sure if your calculated value or the document's value (which is zero) would win.

Given that, it becomes pretty confusing to have a document property for the sole purpose of trying to fill it during indexing, which is why it's usually a better option to have a class that represents the mapped state, and then implementing `AbstractIndexCreationTask<TDocument, TReduceResult>` where the `TReduceResult` class would only contain the result of your mapping, namely the `Name` and `Popularity` columns.

Then when you query from, you can use `.ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto<T>()` to get your results from the stored index results, not from the document store.

Comment: Sorry - it should be DenormalizedReference<ArtistTest>

Comment: But this looks spot on - thanks for taking the time :)

Comment: Hmmm - I can't use ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto on a lucenequery